# What are the key differences between Spack and Conda package managers?

Tags: conda, package-managers, spack

What are the main differences between Spack and Conda package managers?
Which applications are more suitable in one or the other?

Based on the Spack documentation, it is meant to be used for the supercomputers.
But which exact benefits does it bring?

Does it make sense to use Spack over Conda for personal use?

I guess Conda is more Python-focused, while spack is more versatile?
But I couldn't find any detailed information on the actual differences.

Comment: I think Reddit would be a more appropriate forum for this type of question.

Comment: Could I kindly ask why? There are several similar questions on SO asking for the difference between "pip and conda", "Conda and Anaconda", "pip and apt-get", etc. How has Reddit become a more appropriate forum for software-related questions than SO?

Comment: OP questions appear broader than *programming* (SO's topic). Conda vs Pip is narrowly about *Python* package management; Spack vs Conda is about generic software management. Typical users of Spack are on HPCs and use it to load specialized CLI tools, e.g., for chemical simulations or bioinformatics. If you want to stay in SE, then ServerFault might be better, since the main question here is about managing software potential in a server context.

Answer (score 2):

One deeper difference between the two is that Conda installs precompiled packages, whereas with Spack, the software is compiled on your computer (unless you happen to be using a build cache, but nevermind that). This means that if you want a self-consistent set of packages with Conda, your options may be limited because they're compiled in a finite number of ways. If you only need a few packages, and/or you intend to use the packages you install separately in the sense that they don't depend on each other, then Conda may be a good way to go. On the other hand, if you want to use a particular compiler with a particular MPI flavor to build HDF5 which you then want to use to build your own software in a way where everything is internally consistent, then Spack is a strong option. Roughly speaking, Conda can be simpler and quicker to get an installation done, but Spack provides flexibility and customizability (on account of being built to support complex software stacks on HPC systems).